# Issues with xts::to.period causing R to crash

Tags: r, xts

I am using xts and am loading 100 to 1000 files in a loop.  Each file is between 50k to 300k lines.  I am using the latest version of R 2.15.1 on Windows 7 64 bit.  I have the same issue on Ubuntu Linux with R version 2.14.X.

The code below will regularly crash R:

```
library(xts)
N <- 1e6
for(i in 1:1000) {
  allTimes <- Sys.time()-N:1
  x <- NULL
  x <- xts(,allTimes)
  sampTimes <- allTimes[seq(1,length(allTimes),by=2)]
  y <- merge(xts(seq_along(sampTimes), sampTimes), allTimes)
  y <- na.locf(y)
  y <- to.period(y, 'seconds', 10)
  index(y) <- index(to.period(x, 'seconds', 10))
}
```

Comment: It sounds like you're running out of memory. You say you tried this on Ubuntu, but you don't say whether crashes occurred. Do you have swap space on your Ubuntu machine?

Comment: Care to share the code you're using? You can try debugging with browser(). That way, you "get into" the function and get to poke around. It's a lot of fun.

Comment: A couple of things.  It seems that R does not like the usage of print and reading files.  Using a progress bar has helped R behave.  R Studio still has issues.  Applies to both linux and windows.

Comment: I just upgraded R to latest on the linux box.  Now seeing this. > DATTick <- parseTickDataFromDir(tickerDirSecond, "seconds",10, fun)
  |=======                                                               |  10%
 *** caught segfault ***
address 0x10, cause 'memory not mapped'

Traceback:
 1: scan(file = inputFile, sep = ",", skip = 1, what = list(Date = "",     Time = "", Close = 0, Volume = 0), quiet = T)
 2: parseTickData(tickerAbsFilenames[i])
 3: parseTickDataFromDir(tickerDirSecond, "seconds", 10, fun)

Comment: [Cross-posted on R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-July/064466.html)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This was [answered on R-devel](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-devel/2012-July/064478.html).  The issue was calling `to.period` on a zero-width xts object would return a OHLC data of random memory locations.  For example:

```
library(xts)
x <- xts(,Sys.time()-10:1)
y <- to.period(x)
y
#                           x.Open       x.High         x.Low       x.Close
# 2012-07-23 15:47:30 4.25426e-314 2.36246e-300 1.428936e-316 1.428936e-316
```

Since aggregating "no data" doesn't make sense, I have patched `to.period` to throw an error when run on zero-width/length objects (revision 690 on R-Forge).

Instead of running `to.period` on a zero-width object, just create a temporary xts object full of ones and run `to.period` on that.  This will work with the xts currently on CRAN.

```
library(xts)
N <- 1e6
for(i in 1:100) {
  allTimes <- Sys.time()-N:1
  x <- NULL
  x <- xts(,allTimes)
  sampTimes <- allTimes[seq(1,length(allTimes),by=2)]
  y <- merge(xts(seq_along(sampTimes), sampTimes), allTimes)
  y <- na.locf(y)
  y <- to.period(y, 'seconds', 10)
  tmp <- xts(rep(1,length(allTimes)), allTimes)
  index(y) <- index(to.period(tmp, 'seconds', 10))
}
```